# How to optimize SciKit one-class training time?

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, classification, svm

Essentially my questions is the same as [SciKit One-class SVM classifier training time increases exponentially with size of training data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715835/scikit-one-class-svm-classifier-training-time-increases-exponentially-with-size/45472297), but no one has figured out the problem.

It seems to run fine for somewhere in the 10s of thousands, but 100s of thousands take very long. And I want to run it on 10s of millions, but I don't want to wait a day and a half (maybe even more) for nothing to come of it. Is there a faster way about it, or should I use something else?

Comment: If you are also looking at anomaly detection, perhaps Isolation Forests are worth a look? They have the advantage of being fast and unsupervised, they've also performed favourably to state of the art algorithms - Liu (2008). Isolation Forests

Comment: I should mention that there is an sklearn implementation in `sklearn.ensembles`, which makes it easy to use

Comment: Ah I wanted to use both novelty detection and outlier detection since my training class only consists of one class, and I am unsure if that class is an outlier or an inlier compare to the other class. (I am only doing binary classifier.) But if Isolation Forests are faster, then I might as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *very* junior in this field, so take this with a grain of salt.

Isolation Forests appear to be an efficient solution for outlier detection. They have been shown to perform well against other popular algorithms [Liu, 2008]. Also, One-class SVMs are somewhat susceptible to anomalies according to scikit learn. The anomalies in your Class 1 could overlap with Class 2 and cause data to be mislabeled... perhaps taking subsets of your samples and using them to create an ensemble of SVMs could avoid this (and still save you time, depending on the size of the subsets), but Isolation Forests naturally do this.

For further reading, this seems like a good reference paper on the topic
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~davidc/pubs/NDreview2014.pdf

It mentions clustering and distance methods which may be applicable in your case. I think it's best to do a lot of reading and make sure you understand the different strengths/weaknesses of the algorithms. Especially since I'm in the process of doing that and really can't give solid advice even if I knew the specifics of your problem.

Note re:distance based algorithms. I know some are optimized, but I think the general complaint is that they have high computation complexity. Many clustering/distance/probability based algorithms also have weaknesses dealing with high dimensionality data.

Comment: But would you happen to know an efficient solution for novelty detection? edit: I am using these definitions: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

Comment: I don't. But a brief search landed me with this for [nearest neighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#k-d-tree) (distance). I'm sure a lot of other methods in that paper will have sklearn implementations, after that it's just checking their computational complexity.