# Python: Parallelize OneClassSVM training

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using [OneClassSVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) to train a dataset(4641820, 43). I submit my job into a [cluster](http://amamaster.l3s.uni-hannover.de/). It takes three consecutive days to complete the training. As a beginner, I have studied also [LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) & [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) where I have seen a parameter `**n_jobs**: The number of jobs to run in parallel for both fit and predict`. I also studied  n_jobs=-1 means that the computation will be dispatched on all the CPUs of the computer. But for OneClassSVM, I didn't find anything like that. Doe's OneClassSVM internally doing this and How can I reduce my training time or is it normal according to my dataset?

My classifier parameter settings

```
OneClassSVM(cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.1,
      kernel='linear', max_iter=-1, nu=0.014371518068343882,
      random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

There is a related question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715835/scikit-one-class-svm-classifier-training-time-increases-exponentially-with-size/45472297) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472516/how-to-optimize-scikit-one-class-training-time) but I didn't find any positive solutions for me.